# Gradle build cache is not enabled for task

Tags: gradle, kotlin, incremental-build, gradle-cache

I have enabled gradle build cache for my project. But, we are using some non-built in tasks like npm-install from third party plugins. Gradle is not enabling cache for these tasks. For example it shows something like below when such task is executed :

```
Task :data-export-ui-kjs:npm-configure
Build cache key for task ':data-export-ui-kjs:npm-configure' is bbe0dafcd467a2afb2834acafe2993f5
Caching disabled for task ':data-export-ui-kjs:npm-configure': Caching has not been enabled for the task
```

Is there a way to enable build cache for such non-builtin tasks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A task needs to opt-in to being cacheable (see [Cacheable tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html#sec:task_output_caching_details)), since it doesn't make sense for every task to be cacheable.

Opting in can happen by annotating the task with [@CacheableTask](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/CacheableTask.html) or by using `task.outputs.cacheIf { true }`, so you could do that for the npm configure task.

Note that cacheable tasks need to [declare their inputs and outputs correctly](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html#sec:task_output_caching_inputs). If they don't, then you may experience invalid build failures.

Comment: So, how to enable cache for a task?

Comment: My answer already contains (@CacheableTask or `task.outputs.cacheIf { true }`). For more documentation see the [Gradle user guide section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html#enable_caching_of_non_cacheable_tasks).

Answer (score 1):

[Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html) says:

> There are third party plugins that work well with the build cache. The most prominent examples are the Android plugin 3.1+ and the Kotlin plugin 1.2.21+. For other third party plugins, check their documentation to find out whether they support the build cache.

So it depends on the plugin which provides the task `npm-configure`.

If you are using the `gradle-node-plugin` from SRS, it should work since version 1.2.0 according to [their changelog](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/blob/fc7bba527c5ba4289aa4b49540af14855b96721f/CHANGELOG.md).