# Where cache is added to tasks?

Tags: android, kotlin

At startup command:

```
./gradlew :app:ktlintCheck --info
```

Output errors to console:

```
Task :app:ktlintDebugAndroidTestCheck FAILED  
Caching disabled for task ':app:ktlintDebugAndroidTestCheck': Caching has not been enabled for the task  
Task ':app:ktlintDebugAndroidTestCheck' is not up-to-date because:  
Task has not declared any outputs.
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50561084/995891 - I don't think the "no cache" part is an error. "Task has not declared any outputs." on the other hand seems wrong.